# Removing %20 from fullname Aweber

Tags: javascript, wordpress, aweber

Passing variables from Aweber to wordpress Thank you page - However the name appears as follows:
firstname%20Lastname

code used

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var formData = function() {  var query_string = (location.search) ? ((location.search.indexOf('#') != -1) ? location.search.substring(1, location.search.indexOf('#')) : location.search.substring(1)) : '';  
var elements = [];  
if(query_string) {     
    var pairs = query_string.split("&");     
    for(i in pairs) {     
        if (typeof pairs[i] == 'string') {           
            var tmp = pairs[i].split("=");           
            var queryKey = unescape(tmp[0]);           
            queryKey = (queryKey.charAt(0) == 'c') ? queryKey.replace(/s/g, "_") : queryKey;   
            elements[queryKey] = unescape(tmp[1]);      
             }    
       } 
 }  
return {     
    display: function(key) {         
        if(elements[key]) {           
             document.write(elements[key]);         
         } 
         else {         
               document.write("<!--If desired, replace everything between these quotes with a default in case there is no data in the query string.-->");          
          }     
  }   
} 
}
(); </script>

then
    <script>// <![CDATA[
formData.display('fullname')
// ]]></script>
```

tried
      decodeURI(formData.display("fullname"))
But it doesn't work???
I've searched and searched and cant figure it out - Please anyone help???
Thanks.

Comment: You might be looking for `decodeURIComponent`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: tried decodeURIComponent(formData.display("fullname"))

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing its part of a Wordpress plugin, so you just want a fix right :)

Try replacing this part:

```
return {  
    display: function(key) {         
        if(elements[key]) {           
            document.write(elements[key]);         
        } else {         
            document.write("<!--If desired, replace everything between these quotes with a default in case there is no data in the query string.-->");          
        }     
    }
}
```

With this:

```
return {
    display: function(key) {         
        if(elements[key]) {           
            document.write(decodeURIComponent(elements[key]));  
        } else {         
            document.write("<!--If desired, replace everything between these quotes with a default in case there is no data in the query string.-->");          
        }     
    }
}
```